# Cosine similarities and totally different results using same source

Tags: python, machine-learning, cosine-similarity, word-embedding, machine-translation

I am learning word embeddings and cosine similarity. My data is composed of two sets of same words but in 2 different languages.

I did two tests:

1. I measured the cosine similarity using the average of the word vectors (that I think it should be called soft cosine similarity instead)
2. I measured the cosine similarity using the word vectors

Should I expect to obtain quite the same results? I noticed that sometimes I have two opposite results. Since I am new on this, I am trying to figure out if I did something wrong or if there is an explanation behind. According to what I have been reading, soft cosine similarity should be more accurate than the usual cosine similarity.

Now, it's time for some data to show you. Unfortunately I can't post a part of my data (the words themselves), but I will try my best to give you the max of information I can give you.

Some other details before:

- I am using FastText to create the embeddings, skipgram model with
  default parameters.
- For the soft cosine similarity, I am using [Scipy
  spatial distance cosine](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html). Following some people suggestions, to measure cosine similarity it seems that I should subtract 1 from the formula, such as:

`(1-distance.cosine(data['LANG1_AVG'].iloc[i],data['LANG2_AVG'].iloc[i]))`

- For the usual cosine similarity I am using the [Fast Vector cosine similarity](https://github.com/Babylonpartners/fastText_multilingual/blob/master/fasttext.py) from [FastText Multilingual](https://github.com/Babylonpartners/fastText_multilingual), defined in this way:

  `@classmethod
  def cosine_similarity(cls, vec_a, vec_b):
      """Compute cosine similarity between vec_a and vec_b"""
      return np.dot(vec_a, vec_b) / \
          (np.linalg.norm(vec_a) * np.linalg.norm(vec_b))`

As you will see from the image here, for some words I obtained the same results or quite similar using the two methods. For others I obtained two totally different results. How can I explain this?

[image: My data v2]

Comment: Generate a minimal example. If you can't show the words you are using try some other words that you can show.

Comment: What is the formula for the average? I never heard of calculating vector similarities that way, it seems weird as well as you want to keep information about the position of one vector compared to the other, which you lose if you compute the average... And also, why do you expect the results to be similar?

Comment: @roadrunner66 I added an example

Comment: @qmeeus I am not sure that they should be similar. It's the first time I am doing this so I am a little confused about it: I asked around me and they said that it could be only a problem of vector dimensions. The formula of the average is a simple statistical average on values of the same word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more additional research, I found a 2014 paper ([Soft Similarity and Soft Cosine Measure:
Similarity of Features in Vector Space Model](http://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/cys/v18n3/v18n3a7.pdf)) that explains when and how it could be useful to use averages of the features, and it explains also what is exactly a soft cosine measure:

> Our idea is more general: we propose to modify the
>   manner of calculation of similarity in Vector Space Model
>   taking into account similarity of features. If we apply
>   this idea to the cosine measure, then the “soft cosine
>   measure” is introduced, as opposed to traditional “hard
>   cosine”, which ignores similarity of features. Note that
>   when we consider similarity of each pair of features, it
>   is equivalent to introducing new features in the VSM.
>   Essentially, we have a matrix of similarity between pairs
>   of features and all these features represent new dimensions in the VSM.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the soft similarity between two vectors x and y is given by (avg(x) * avg(y)) / (abs(avg(x)) * abs(avg(y))) = sign(avg(x) * avg(y)), which is either 1 or -1 depending on whether the averages have the same sign or not. This is probably not very helpful.

The cosine similarity is calculated with (x * y) / (||x|| * ||y||). 2 vectors pointing in the same direction will have a similarity of 1 (x * x = ||x||^2), 2 vectors pointing to the opposite direction, a similarity of -1 (x * -x = -||x||^2) and 2 perpendicular vectors a similarity of 0 ((1,0)*(0,1)=0). If the angle between the vectors is not equal to one of 0, 90, 180 or 270, you will have a similarity score between (but not equal to) -1 and 1.

Bottom line: forget about the averages and only use the cosine similarity. Note that the cosine similarity compares the orientation and not the length of the vectors.

PS: the translation of "able" in french is "capable" and not "able" ;)